# Implementation of a softmax activation function for neural networks

Tags: c++, math, neural-network, softmax

I am using a [Softmax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_activation_function) activation function in the last layer of a neural network. But I have problems with a safe implementation of this function.

A naive implementation would be this one:

```
Vector y = mlp(x); // output of the neural network without softmax activation function
for(int f = 0; f < y.rows(); f++)
  y(f) = exp(y(f));
y /= y.sum();
```

This does not work very well for > 100 hidden nodes because the y will be `NaN` in many cases (if y(f) > 709, exp(y(f)) will return inf). I came up with this version:

```
Vector y = mlp(x); // output of the neural network without softmax activation function
for(int f = 0; f < y.rows(); f++)
  y(f) = safeExp(y(f), y.rows());
y /= y.sum();
```

where `safeExp` is defined as

```
double safeExp(double x, int div)
{
  static const double maxX = std::log(std::numeric_limits<double>::max());
  const double max = maxX / (double) div;
  if(x > max)
    x = max;
  return std::exp(x);
}
```

This function limits the input of exp. In most of the cases this works but not in all cases and I did not really manage to find out in which cases it does not work. When I have 800 hidden neurons in the previous layer it does not work at all.

However, even if this worked I somehow "distort" the result of the ANN. Can you think of any other way to calculate the correct solution? Are there any C++ libraries or tricks that I can use to calculate the exact output of this ANN?

**edit:** The solution provided by Itamar Katz is:

```
Vector y = mlp(x); // output of the neural network without softmax activation function
double ymax = maximal component of y
for(int f = 0; f < y.rows(); f++)
  y(f) = exp(y(f) - ymax);
y /= y.sum();
```

And it really is mathematically the same. In practice however, some small values become 0 because of the floating point precision. I wonder why nobody ever writes these implementation details down in textbooks.

Comment: "I wonder why nobody ever writes these implementation details down in textbooks."

I've always wondered the same thing!

Comment: "It really is mathematically the same" - reading further, someone says your method is preferred due to numerical stability.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968722/softmax-function-python

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First go to log scale, i.e calculate `log(y)` instead of `y`. The log of the numerator is trivial. In order to calculate the log of the denominator, you can use the following 'trick': [http://lingpipe-blog.com/2009/06/25/log-sum-of-exponentials/](https://web.archive.org/web/20091004064300/http://lingpipe-blog.com/2009/06/25/log-sum-of-exponentials/)

Comment: A perfect solution. I will add the code in a minute. Could you confirm that please? Thank you very much.

Comment: It doesn't seem correct; follow the algebra of what `log(y(f))` is: **log(y(f))=log(exp(y(f))) - log(sum(exp(y(f)))** and plug in the mentioned 'trick' result for the log of the sum.

Comment: ln(y_f) = ln(exp(a_f)) - ln(sum over f' exp(a_f')) = af - ln[sum over f' exp(m)/exp(m) * exp(a_f')] = a_f - m - ln(sum over f' exp(-m) * exp(a_f)) = a_f - m - ln[sum over f' exp(a_f'-m)] <=> y_f exp(a_f-m)/(sum over f' exp(a_f' - m)). a_f is y_f before exp() in the listed code above. Where is the error? :D

Comment: And I did a test with a_1 = 1, a_2 = 2, a_3 = 3. The vector y is in both cases y = (0.090031,0.24473,0.66524)^T. At least in this case it seems to be correct.

Answer (score 8):

I know it's already answered but I'll post here a step-by-step anyway.

put on log:

```
zj = wj . x + bj
oj = exp(zj)/sum_i{ exp(zi) }
log oj = zj - log sum_i{ exp(zi) }
```

Let m be the max_i { zi } use the log-sum-exp trick:

```
log oj = zj - log {sum_i { exp(zi + m - m)}}
   = zj - log {sum_i { exp(m) exp(zi - m) }},
   = zj - log {exp(m) sum_i {exp(zi - m)}}
   = zj - m - log {sum_i { exp(zi - m)}}
```

the term exp(zi-m) can suffer underflow if m is much greater than other z_i, but that's ok since this means z_i is irrelevant on the softmax output after normalization. final results is:

```
oj = exp (zj - m - log{sum_i{exp(zi-m)}})
```

Comment: Thanks! Your answer helps! You mentioned "but that's ok since this means z_i is irrelevant on the softmax output after normalization", do you mean if underflow of `exp(zi-m)` happens. It does not add much error in the result?

Comment: Sorry the late reply. Yes, if m >> zi then exp(zi-m) would be near 0, the underflow just changes it to 0, which doesn't change much of the final results.