# MNIST NN from scratch, output converge on one number

Tags: python, neural-network

After watching Samson Zhang's video and 3blue1brown I tried to write the NN from scratch. (The code is heavily referenced from Samson's, but did go through the whole derivation of how he got the formula) I wrote down the equations and derivation to make sure I fully understand how it worked. But when I run the model, accuracy starts going down at around 17% and seems to all verge on 1 number and when they do I also get error messages.

`RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp a2=np.exp(z)/sum(np.exp(z))`

`RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in divide a2=np.exp(z)/sum(np.exp(z))`

The dimensions for each input, node, weights, biases are as below.

a0(input) = m x 784

w1 = 784 x 20

b1 = 1 x 20

a1 = m x 20

w2 = 20 x 10

b2 = 1 x 10

a2(output) = m x 10

y(one_hot_encoded) = m x 10

I have tried changing the learning rate(alpha) to a smaller number, but they all lead to the same error in the end.

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd

m, n = data.shape
x_train=data[0:m,1:785]
y_train=data[0:m,0]
x_train=x_train/255

def init_param():
    w1=np.random.rand(784,20)-0.5
    b1=np.random.rand(1,20)-0.5
    w2=np.random.rand(20,10)-0.5
    b2=np.random.rand(1,10)-0.5
    
    return w1, b1, w2, b2

def ReLU(z):
    return np.maximum(z,0)

def Softmax(z):
    a2=np.exp(z)/sum(np.exp(z))
    return a2

def f_propagation(a0,w1,b1,w2,b2):
    z1 = a0.dot(w1)+b1 # m x 20
    a1 = ReLU(z1)         # m x 20
    z2 = a1.dot(w2)+b2 # m x 10
    a2 = Softmax(z2)      # m x 10 
    return z1, a1, z2, a2

def dev_ReLU(z):
    return z>0

def one_hotencode(y):
    y_hat=np.zeros((np.size(y),10))
    y_hat[np.arange(y.size),y] = 1
    return y_hat

def b_propagation(x,y,z1,w1,a1,z2,w2,a2):
    y_hat = one_hotencode(y)
    dadc = a2 - y_hat # m x 10 Start from here
    dw2 = 1/m * (a1.T.dot(dadc)) #20 x 10
    db2 = 1/m * np.sum(dadc,axis=0) #1 x 10
    dw1 = 1/m * x.T.dot((w2.dot(dadc.T).T * dev_ReLU(z1))) # 784 x 20
    db1 = 1/m * np.sum((w2.dot(dadc.T).T * dev_ReLU(z1)),axis=0) #1 x 20
    return dw2, db2, dw1, db1

def update_param(w1, b1, w2, b2, dw1, db1, dw2, db2, alpha):
    w1 = w1 - alpha * dw1
    b1 = b1 - alpha * db1
    w2 = w2 - alpha * dw2
    b2 = b2 - alpha * db2 
    return w1, b1, w2, b2

def get_predictions(A2):
    return np.argmax(A2, 0)

def get_accuracy(predictions, Y):
    print(predictions, Y)
    return np.sum(predictions == Y) / Y.size

def gradient_descent(x, y, alpha=0.01, iterations=500):
    w1, b1, w2, b2 = init_param()
    for i in range(iterations):
        z1, a1, z2, a2 = f_propagation(x,w1,b1,w2,b2)
        dw2, db2, dw1, db1 = b_propagation(x,y,z1,w1,a1,z2,w2,a2)
        w1, b1, w2, b2 = update_param(w1, b1, w2, b2, dw1, db1, dw2, db2, alpha)
        if i % 10 == 0:
            print("Iteration: ", i)
            predictions = get_predictions(a2.T)
            print(get_accuracy(predictions, y))
        
    return w1, b1, w2, b2

w1, b1, w2, b2 = gradient_descent(x_train, y_train, 0.01, 500)
```

Results:

```
Iteration:  0
[5 0 2 ... 1 7 3] [4 3 7 ... 8 1 1]
0.08547619047619047
Iteration:  10
[5 7 2 ... 1 3 3] [4 3 7 ... 8 1 1]
0.09669047619047619
Iteration:  20
[5 7 7 ... 1 3 3] [4 3 7 ... 8 1 1]
0.10857142857142857
Iteration:  30
[5 7 7 ... 1 3 3] [4 3 7 ... 8 1 1]
0.11978571428571429
Iteration:  40
[5 7 7 ... 1 3 3] [4 3 7 ... 8 1 1]
0.12797619047619047
Iteration:  50
[5 7 7 ... 1 3 3] [4 3 7 ... 8 1 1]
0.13035714285714287
Iteration:  60
[5 7 7 ... 1 3 3] [4 3 7 ... 8 1 1]
0.12047619047619047
Iteration:  70
[5 1 1 ... 1 3 3] [4 3 7 ... 8 1 1]
0.09740476190476191
Iteration:  80
[3 1 1 ... 1 3 3] [4 3 7 ... 8 1 1]
0.0975952380952381
Iteration:  90
[3 1 1 ... 1 3 3] [4 3 7 ... 8 1 1]
0.11626190476190476
Iteration:  100
[1 1 1 ... 1 1 1] [4 3 7 ... 8 1 1]
0.12088095238095238
Iteration:  110
[1 1 1 ... 1 1 1] [4 3 7 ... 8 1 1]
0.112
Iteration:  120
[1 1 1 ... 1 1 1] [4 3 7 ... 8 1 1]
0.11152380952380953
Iteration:  130
[1 1 1 ... 1 1 1] [4 3 7 ... 8 1 1]
0.11152380952380953
Iteration:  140
[1 1 1 ... 1 1 1] [4 3 7 ... 8 1 1]
0.11152380952380953
/tmp/ipykernel_29/2242731165.py:13: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
  a2=np.exp(z)/sum(np.exp(z))
/tmp/ipykernel_29/2242731165.py:13: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in divide
  a2=np.exp(z)/sum(np.exp(z))
```

Comment: Try lowering the learning rate alpha to 10^-4

Comment: @Caridorc That did not work, unfortunately. Same results as before. :(

Comment: Softmax is numerically unstable, (exp gives huge outputs, this can be messy given the approximate number representation inside computers), I suggest reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42599498/numerically-stable-softmax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close to a working solution, here is a working version of your code where I just gave closer attention to the computation of the softmax to avoid overflows and underflows:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
import numpy as np

# Load the MNIST dataset
mnist = load_digits()

# Extract the features (input) and labels (output)
x_train = mnist.data  # Input features
y_train = mnist.target  # Output labels

# Normalize the input features
x_train = x_train / 255.0

def init_param():
    w1 = np.random.rand(64, 20) - 0.5
    b1 = np.random.rand(1, 20) - 0.5
    w2 = np.random.rand(20, 10) - 0.5
    b2 = np.random.rand(1, 10) - 0.5
    
    return w1, b1, w2, b2

def ReLU(z):
    return np.maximum(z, 0)

def Softmax(z):
    exp_z = np.exp(z - np.max(z, axis=1, keepdims=True))
    softmax = exp_z / np.sum(exp_z, axis=1, keepdims=True)
    return softmax

def f_propagation(a0, w1, b1, w2, b2):
    z1 = np.dot(a0, w1) + b1  # m x 20
    a1 = ReLU(z1)             # m x 20
    z2 = np.dot(a1, w2) + b2  # m x 10
    a2 = Softmax(z2)          # m x 10
    return z1, a1, z2, a2

def dev_ReLU(z):
    return z > 0

def one_hotencode(y):
    y_hat = np.zeros((y.size, 10))
    y_hat[np.arange(y.size), y] = 1
    return y_hat

def b_propagation(x, y, z1, w1, a1, z2, w2, a2):
    y_hat = one_hotencode(y)
    dadz2 = a2 - y_hat  # m x 10
    dw2 = np.dot(a1.T, dadz2)  # 20 x 10
    db2 = np.sum(dadz2, axis=0)  # 1 x 10
    dadz1 = np.dot(dadz2, w2.T) * dev_ReLU(z1)  # m x 20
    dw1 = np.dot(x.T, dadz1)  # 64 x 20
    db1 = np.sum(dadz1, axis=0)  # 1 x 20
    return dw2, db2, dw1, db1

def update_param(w1, b1, w2, b2, dw1, db1, dw2, db2, alpha):
    w1 = w1 - alpha * dw1
    b1 = b1 - alpha * db1
    w2 = w2 - alpha * dw2
    b2 = b2 - alpha * db2
    return w1, b1, w2, b2

def get_predictions(A2):
    return np.argmax(A2, axis=1)

def get_accuracy(predictions, Y):
    return np.mean(predictions == Y)

def gradient_descent(x, y, alpha=0.01, iterations=500):
    m, n = x.shape
    w1, b1, w2, b2 = init_param()
    
    for i in range(iterations):
        z1, a1, z2, a2 = f_propagation(x, w1, b1, w2, b2)
        dw2, db2, dw1, db1 = b_propagation(x, y, z1, w1, a1, z2, w2, a2)
        w1, b1, w2, b2 = update_param(w1, b1, w2, b2, dw1, db1, dw2, db2, alpha)
        
        if i % 10 == 0:
            print("Iteration: ", i)
            predictions = get_predictions(a2)
            accuracy = get_accuracy(predictions, y)
            print("Accuracy:", accuracy)
        
    return w1, b1, w2, b2

w1, b1, w2, b2 = gradient_descent(x_train, y_train, 0.0001, 5000)
```

Comment: Fortunately, I realized it was the softmax that was causing the problem and managed to fix it. Thanks for the feedback.