# Softmax function in neural network (Python)

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

I am learning the neural network and implement it in python. I firstly define a softmax function, I follow the solution given by this question [Softmax function - python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968722/softmax-function-python). The following is my codes:

```
def softmax(A):
    """
    Computes a softmax function. 
    Input: A (N, k) ndarray.
    Returns: (N, k) ndarray.
    """
    s = 0
    e = np.exp(A)
    s = e / np.sum(e, axis =0)
    return s
```

I was given a test codes to see if the `sofmax` function is correct. The `test_array` is the test data and `test_output` is the correct output for `softmax(test_array)`. The following is the test codes:

```
# Test if your function works correctly.
test_array = np.array([[0.101,0.202,0.303],
                       [0.404,0.505,0.606]]) 
test_output = [[ 0.30028906,  0.33220277,  0.36750817],
               [ 0.30028906,  0.33220277,  0.36750817]]
print(np.allclose(softmax(test_array),test_output))
```

However according to the `softmax` function that I defined. Testing the data by `softmax(test_array)` returns

```
print (softmax(test_array))

[[ 0.42482427  0.42482427  0.42482427]
 [ 0.57517573  0.57517573  0.57517573]]
```

Could anyone indicate me what is the problem of the function `softmax` that I defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your sum. You are summing in axis 0 where you should keep axis 0 untouched.

To sum over all the entries in the same example, i.e., in the same line, you have to use axis 1 instead.

```
def softmax(A):
    """
    Computes a softmax function. 
    Input: A (N, k) ndarray.
    Returns: (N, k) ndarray.
    """
    e = np.exp(A)
    return e / np.sum(e, axis=1, keepdims=True)
```

Use `keepdims` to preserve shape and be able to divide `e` by the sum.

In your example, `e` evaluates to:

```
[[ 1.10627664  1.22384801  1.35391446]
 [ 1.49780395  1.65698552  1.83308438]]
```

then the sum for each example (denominator in the `return` line) is:

```
[[ 3.68403911]
 [ 4.98787384]]
```

The function then divides each line by its sum and gives the result you have in `test_output`.

As MaxU pointed out, it is a good practice to remove the max before exponentiating, in order to avoid overflow:

```
e = np.exp(A - np.sum(A, axis=1, keepdims=True))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
In [327]: def softmax(A):
     ...:     e = np.exp(A)
     ...:     return  e / e.sum(axis=1).reshape((-1,1))

In [328]: softmax(test_array)
Out[328]:
array([[ 0.30028906,  0.33220277,  0.36750817],
       [ 0.30028906,  0.33220277,  0.36750817]])
```

or better this version which will prevent overflow when large values are exponentiated:

```
def softmax(A):
    e = np.exp(A - np.max(A, axis=1).reshape((-1, 1)))
    return  e / e.sum(axis=1).reshape((-1,1))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can print `np.sum(e, axis=0)` by yourself. You will see it is an array with 3 elements `[ 2.60408059  2.88083353  3.18699884]`. Then `e / np.sum(e, axis=0)` represents the 3-element array above divides every element of `e`(which is a 3-element array too). Apparently it is not you want.

You should change `np.sum(e, axis=0)` to `np.sum(e, axis=1, keepdims=True)`, so that you will get

```
[[ 3.68403911]                  
 [ 4.98787384]]
```

instead, which is what you actually want. And you will get the right result.

And I recommand you read [the rules of broadcasting in numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html). It describes how plus/subtract/multiply/divide works on two arrays with different sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this may be enlightening:

```
>>> np.sum(test_output, axis=1)
array([ 1.,  1.])
```

Notice that each row is normalized. In other words, they want you to compute softmax for each row independently.

Comment: Thanks @Mateen Ulhaq