# Adapting pytorch softmax function

Tags: pytorch, softmax

I am currently looking into the softmax function and I would like to adapt the orignally implemented for ome small tests.

I have been to the docs but there wasn't that much of usefull information about the function. This is the [pytorch python implementation](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/_modules/torch/nn/modules/activation.html#Softmax):

```
def __init__(self, dim=None):
    super(Softmax, self).__init__()
    self.dim = dim

def __setstate__(self, state):
    self.__dict__.update(state)
    if not hasattr(self, 'dim'):
        self.dim = None

def forward(self, input):
    return F.softmax(input, self.dim, _stacklevel=5)
```

Where can I find the F.softmax impementation?

One off the things I want to try for instance is the soft-margin softmax described here: [Soft-Margin Softmax for Deep Classification](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f220/ef68612e68a5708001f2b596d742b941e773.pdf)

Where would be the best place to start?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The F.softmax implementation is here  
https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/functional.py  
However, this just calls the C implementation. I suggest you just replace F.softmax(...) with your custom softmax function implemented in torch.

Comment: Reading in the different forums I was more and more leaning to that. Ill give it a try, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Softmax Implementation in PyTorch and Numpy

A Softmax function is defined as follows:

[image: Softmax function definition]

A direct implementation of the above formula is as follows:

```
def softmax(x):
    return np.exp(x) / np.exp(x).sum(axis=0)
```

Above implementation can run into arithmetic overflow because of `np.exp(x)`.

To avoid the overflow, we can divide the numerator and denominator in the softmax equation with a constant `C`. Then the softmax function becomes following:

[image: Softmax with numerator and denominator divided with constant C]

The above approach is implemented in PyTorch and we take `log(C)` as `-max(x)`. Below is the PyTorch implementation:

```
def softmax_torch(x): # Assuming x has atleast 2 dimensions
    maxes = torch.max(x, 1, keepdim=True)[0]
    x_exp = torch.exp(x-maxes)
    x_exp_sum = torch.sum(x_exp, 1, keepdim=True)
    probs = x_exp/x_exp_sum
    return probs
```

A corresponding Numpy equivalent is as follows:

```
def softmax_np(x):
    maxes = np.max(x, axis=1, keepdims=True)[0]
    x_exp = np.exp(x-maxes)
    x_exp_sum = np.sum(x_exp, 1, keepdims=True)
    probs = x_exp/x_exp_sum
    return probs
```

We can compare the results with PyTorch implementation - `torch.nn.functional.softmax` using below snippet:

```
import torch
import numpy as np
if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = torch.randn(1, 3, 5, 10)
    std_pytorch_softmax = torch.nn.functional.softmax(x)
    pytorch_impl = softmax_torch(x)
    numpy_impl = softmax_np(x.detach().cpu().numpy())
    print("Shapes: x --> {}, std --> {}, pytorch impl --> {}, numpy impl --> {}".format(x.shape, std_pytorch_softmax.shape, pytorch_impl.shape, numpy_impl.shape))
    print("Std and torch implementation are same?", torch.allclose(std_pytorch_softmax, pytorch_impl))
    print("Std and numpy implementation are same?", torch.allclose(std_pytorch_softmax, torch.from_numpy(numpy_impl)))
```

References:

- [Softmax discussion](https://cs231n.github.io/linear-classify/#softmax)
- [Discussion on Softmax implementation at PyTorch forumn](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-implement-the-exactly-same-softmax-as-f-softmax-by-pytorch/44263/6)
- [An SO thread on implementation of Softmax in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34968722/6561141)

Comment: Thank you for the very clear explenation. In the mean while i have moved on from the project but i will certainly have a try!