# Implementation of softmax function returns nan for high inputs

Tags: python, softmax

[image]

I am trying to implement softmax at the end of cnn, The output I got is nan and zeros. I am giving high input values to softmax around 10-20k I'm giving an array of `X=[2345,3456,6543,-6789,-9234]`

My function is

```
def softmax (X):
    B=np.exp(X)
    C=np.sum(np.exp(X))
    return B/C
```

I am getting error of `true divide and run time error`

```
C:\Anaconda\envs\deep_learning\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:4: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  after removing the cwd from sys.path.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement the Softmax function in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968722/how-to-implement-the-softmax-function-in-python)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [softmax function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function), you need to iterate all elements in the array and compute the exponential for each individual element then divide it by the sum of the exponential of the all elements:

```
import numpy as np

a = [1,3,5]
for i in a:
    print np.exp(i)/np.sum(np.exp(a))

0.015876239976466765
0.11731042782619837
0.8668133321973349
```

However if the numbers are too big the exponents will probably blow up (computer can not handle such big numbers):

```
a = [2345,3456,6543]
for i in a:
    print np.exp(i)/np.sum(np.exp(a))

__main__:2: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
nan
nan
nan
```

To avoid this, first shift the highest value in array to **zero**. Then compute the softmax. For example, to compute the softmax of `[1, 3, 5]` use `[1-5, 3-5, 5-5]` which is `[-4, -2, 0]`.  Also you may choose the implement it in vectorized way (as you intendet to do in question):

```
def softmax(x):
    f = np.exp(x - np.max(x))  # shift values
    return f / f.sum(axis=0)

softmax([1,3,5])
# prints: array([0.01587624, 0.11731043, 0.86681333])

softmax([2345,3456,6543,-6789,-9234])
# prints: array([0., 0., 1., 0., 0.])
```

For detailed information check out the [cs231n](http://cs231n.github.io/linear-classify/#softmax) course page. The **Practical issues: Numeric stability.** heading is exactly what I'm trying to explain.

Answer (score 5):

In case of applying `softmax` on a large numbers, you can try using *max normalization*:

```
import numpy as np

def softmax (x):
    B=np.exp(x)
    C=np.sum(np.exp(x))
    return B/C

arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

softmax(arr)
# array([0.01165623, 0.03168492, 0.08612854, 0.23412166, 0.63640865])

softmax(arr - max(arr))
# array([0.01165623, 0.03168492, 0.08612854, 0.23412166, 0.63640865])
```

As you can see, this does not affect the result of `softmax`. 
Applying this on your `softmax`:

```
def softmax(x):
    B = np.exp(x - max(x))
    C = np.sum(B)
    return B/C
op_arr = np.array([2345,3456,6543,-6789,-9234])
softmax(op_arr)
# array([0., 0., 1., 0., 0.])
```

Answer (score 1):

When I run the same code, I get:

```
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
```

This is not very surprising since `e^(6543)` is around `0.39 * 10^2842` probably causing an overflow in the following operations.

To do : normalize your data before giving it to softmax: could you divide it by 1000 before giving it to softmax, so that, instead of having input in [-20000,20000], you would have an input as floats in [-20, 20].