# Softmax function returning nan or all zeros in a neural network

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, activation-function

I am designing a neural network to predict MNIST dataset from scratch with layers 784, 500, 500, 10.
In forward propagation function my softmax function is returning nan values, I tried solving it bu subtracting maximum value as below

```
def softmax(a):
    B = np.exp(a - np.max(a))
    C = np.sum(B)
    return B/C
```

after trying this, my softmax returns all zeros.

forward propagation function looks like the following:

```
def fprop(self, batch_input, train=True):   
        inputl = batch_input
        self.net['z%s' % 0] = batch_input
        self.net['a%s' % 0] = batch_input
        for l in range(1, self.num_layers + 1):
            w = self.parameters['W%s' % l]
            dp = np.dot(w, inputl)
            pre_act = dp + self.parameters['b%s' % l]
            self.net['a%s' % l] = pre_act
            if self.activations_func[l] == 'sigmoid':
                self.net['z%s' % l] = sigmoid(self.net['a%s' % l])
            elif self.activations_func[l] == 'tanh':
                self.net['z%s' % l] = tanh(self.net['a%s' % l])
            elif self.activations_func[l] == 'relu':
                self.net['z%s' % l] = relu(self.net['a%s' % l])
            elif self.activations_func[l] == 'lrelu':
                self.net['z%s' % l] = lrelu(self.net['a%s' % l], 0.1)
            elif self.activations_func[l] == 'identity':
                self.net['z%s' % l] = identity(self.net['a%s' % l])
            elif self.activations_func[l] == 'softmax':
                self.net['z%s' %l] = softmax(pre_act)
            inputl = self.net['z%s' % l]
```

Comment: I think you will find answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54880369/implementation-of-softmax-function-returns-nan-for-high-inputs
It's probably an overflow error

Comment: @J.Zagdoun I have already tried the solution presented there, as mentioned in my question after that nan values are replaced with zeros, now softmax function is returning all zeros. Now how will I predict the outcome

Comment: Yes indeed, have you checked that the input of your softmax has the right format? all floats for example

Comment: It seems that you initialize the weights with large values, consider lowering them, eg in the range [-0.2, +0.2] or even lower.