# Is it correct to say that any question having the term ”Softmax function” is a duplicate copy?

Tags: logic, meta-tags, logistf

I would like you to leave your comments on: If it is right to say that any question having the term ‘softmax function’ is a duplicate copy to the other questions having the term ‘softmax function’ on it?

Comment: Voting to close. Recommend asking this on the meta.stackoverflow.com site if you disagree with how some question was treated.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is wrong to say that any question with the term “Softmax function” is a duplicate copy question. Why? Because from the Cambridge Dictionary, the meaning of the term ”duplicate copy” is define as “been an exact copy of something or something that is an exact copy of something else”.
Diversity of opinions, questions and answers on the term ”softmax function” should be well come and should not be called duplicate copy. But, instead should be called related, and grouped under related questions.
For more information on how to apply softmax in machine learning, please click the link below: 
[How to use softmax output in python for neural-network and machine-learning to interpret Multinomial Logit Model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60482320)