# Gradient exploding problem in a graph neural network

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, gradient

I have a gradient exploding problem which I couldn't solve after trying for several days. I implemented a custom message passing graph neural network in TensorFlow which is used to predict a continuous value from graph data. Each graph is associated with one target value. Each node of a graph is represented by a node attribute vector, and the edges between nodes are represented by an edge attribute vector.

Within a message passing layer, node attributes are updated in a certain way (e.g., by aggregating other node/edge attributes), and these updated node attributes are returned.

Now, I managed to figure out where the gradient problem occurs in my code. I have the below snippet.

```
to_concat = [neighbors_mean, e]
z = K.concatenate(to_concat, axis=-1)
output = self.Net(z)
```

Here, `neighbors_mean` is the element-wise mean between two node attributes `vi`, `vj` that form the edge having an edge attribute `e`. `Net` is a single layer feed-forward network. With this, the training loss suddenly jumps to NaN after about 30 epochs with a batch size of 32. If the batch size is 128, still the gradients explode after about 200 epochs.

I found that, in this case, the gradients explode because of the edge attribute `e`. If I didn't concatenate `neighbors_mean` with `e` and just used the below code, there would be no gradient explosion.

```
output = self.Net(neighbors_mean)
```

Also I can avoid gradient explosion by sending `e` through a sigmoid function as follows. But this degrades the performance (final MAE), because the values in `e` are mapped to 0-1 range non-linearly. Note that [Rectified Linear Unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_(neural_networks)) (ReLU) instead of sigmoid didn't work.

```
to_concat = [neighbors_mean, tf.math.sigmoid(e)]
z = K.concatenate(to_concat, axis=-1)
output = self.Net(z)
```

Just to mention that `e` carries a single value relating to the distance between the two corresponding nodes and this distance is always in the range 0.5-4. There are no large values or NaNs in `e`.

I have a custom loss function to train this model, but I found that this is not a problem with loss (other losses also led to the same problem). Below is my custom loss function. Note that although this is a single output regression network, the final layer of my NN has two neurons, relating to the mean and log(sigma) of the prediction.

```
def robust_loss(y_true, y_pred):
  """
  Computes the robust loss between labels and predictions.
  """
  mean, sigma = tf.split(y_pred, 2, axis=-1)
  # tried limiting 'sigma' with  sigma = tf.clip_by_value(sigma,-4,1.0) but the gradients still explode
  loss =  np.sqrt(2.0) * K.abs(mean - y_true) * K.exp(-sigma)  + sigma
  return K.mean(loss)
```

I basically tried everything suggested online to avoid gradient explosion.

1. Applied gradient clipping - with `Adam(lr, clipnorm=1, clipvalue=5)` and also with `tf.clip_by_global_norm(gradients, 1.0)`
2. My target variables are always scaled
3. Weights are initialized with `glorot_uniform` distribution
4. Applied regularisation to weights
5. Tried larger batch sizes (till 256, although delayed gradient explosion happens at some point)
6. Tried with reduced learning rate

What am I missing here? I definitely know it has something to do with concatenating `e`. But given that 0.5<e<4, why do the gradients explode in this case? This feature `e` is important to me. What else can I do to avoid numerical overflow in my model?

Comment: Is the graph you mentioned a Directed Acyclic Graph?

Comment: It is undirected, and there could be cycles in the graph.

Comment: Maybe you should introduce some regularization to the node values? It seems what you are trying to solve is analog to a factor graph, the message passing algorithm may have difficulty to converge when the factor graph has cycles. I am not sure if this is related to your problem. Could you please write a more detailed description so that we can analyze, please?

Comment: I think my graphs are not necessarily factor graphs. All my graphs represent crystal structures (so called [crystal graphs](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.120.145301#fulltext)). If the distance between 2 atoms is less than a threshold, I consider them "bonded". With this definition I may have cyclic graphs. Node (atom) attributes are properly normalised. But I believe the problem is in this edge attribute `e`. Because the gradients start to explode only when I concatenate `e`. Please let me know what details you need more. I can update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem thanks to this cool debugging tool [`tf.debugging.check_numerics`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/debugging/check_numerics).

I initially identified concatenating `e` was the problem, and then realised the values that get passed onto `e` are considerably larger than the values in `neighbors_mean` which is concatenated with `e`. Once they are concatenated and sent through a neural network (`Net()` in my code), I observed some outputs in order of hundreds and slowly reaching thousands as the training progresses.

This is problematic as I have a softmax operation within the message passing layer. Note that softmax calculates an exponential (e<sup>xi</sup>/Σe<sup>xj</sup>). Anything above e<sup>709</sup> results in a numerical overflow in Python. This was producing `inf` values and eventually everything becoming `nan` was the problem in my code. So, this is technically not a gradient exploding problem which is why it couldn't be solved with gradient clipping.

**How did I track the issue?**

I put `tf.debugging.check_numerics()` snippets under several layers/tensors I thought were producing nan values. Something like this:

```
tf.debugging.check_numerics(layerN, "LayerN is producing nans!")
```

This produces an `InvalidArgumentError` as soon as the layer outputs become `inf` or `nan` during training.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "trainer.py", line 506, in <module>
    worker.train_model()
  File "trainer.py", line 211, in train_model
    l, tmae = train_step(*batch)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 828, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 855, in _call
    return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)  # pylint: disable=not-callable
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 2943, in __call__
    filtered_flat_args, captured_inputs=graph_function.captured_inputs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 1919, in _call_flat
    ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 560, in call
    ctx=ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py", line 60, in quick_execute
    inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  LayerN is producing nans! : Tensor had NaN values
```

Now we know where the problem is.

**How to solve the issue**

I applied kernel constraints to the neural network weights whose output gets passed onto the softmax function.

```
layers.Dense(x, name="layer1", kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(1e-6), kernel_constraint=min_max_norm(min_value=1e-30, max_value=1.0))
```

This should make sure that all weights are less than 1 and the layer does not produce large outputs. This resolved the problem without degrading the performance.

Alternatively, one could use the [numerically stable implementation of the softmax function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968722/how-to-implement-the-softmax-function-in-python).

Answer (score 1):

Looks great, as you have already followed most of the solutions to resolve gradient exploding problem. Below is the list of all solutions you can try

**Solutions to avoid Gradient Exploding problem**

1. *Appropriate Weight initialization:* utilise appropriate weight Initialization based on the activation function used.

   | Initialization | Activation Function |
   | --- | --- |
   | He | ReLU & variants |
   | LeCun | SELU |
   | Glorot | Softmax, Logistic, None, Tanh |
2. *Redesigning your Neural network:* use fewer layers in neural network and/or use smaller batch size
3. *Choosing Non Saturation activation function*: choose the right activation function with reduced learning rates

   - ReLU
   - Leaky ReLU
   - randomized leaky ReLU (RReLU)
   - parametric leaky ReLU (PReLU)
   - exponential linear unit (ELU)
4. *Batch Normalisation:* Ideally using batch normalisation before/after each layer, based on what works best for your dataset.

   - after each layer [Paper reference](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.03167)

     ```
     model = keras.models.Sequential([
                          keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=[28, 28]),
                          keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
                          keras.layers.Dense(300, activation="elu", 
                          kernel_initializer="he_normal"),
                          keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
                          keras.layers.Dense(100, activation="elu", 
                          kernel_initializer="he_normal"),
                          keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
                          keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax")
              ])
     ```
   - before each layer

     ```
      model = keras.models.Sequential([
                          keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=[28, 28]),
                          keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
                          keras.layers.Dense(300, kernel_initializer="he_normal", use_bias=False),
                          keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
                          keras.layers.Activation("elu"),
                          keras.layers.Dense(100, kernel_initializer="he_normal", use_bias=False),
                          keras.layers.Activation("elu"),
                          keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
                          keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax")
              ])
     ```
5. *Gradient Clipping* : Good default values are clipnorm=1.0 and clipvalue=0.5
6. *Ensure right optimizer is utilised*: Since you have utilised Adam optimizer, check if other optimizer works best for your case. Refer [this documentation](https://keras.io/api/optimizers/) for info on the available optimizers [SGD, RMSprop, Adam, Adadelta, Adagrad, Adamax, Nadam, Ftrl]
7. *Truncated Backpropagation through time*: often works for RNNS refer this [documentation](https://machinelearningmastery.com/gentle-introduction-backpropagation-time/)
8. *Use LSTM*(solution for RNN)
9. *Use weight regularizers on layers*: set `kernel_regularizer` to L1 or L2. [Weight regularizer document reference](https://keras.io/api/layers/regularizers/)

For more information refer to chapter 11 in *Hands on Machine learning with scikit-learn, keras and tensorflow* book by *Aurélien*

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer. I had tried almost all these things for several days but none of them worked. I suspect the problem might be because of the different scales of two tensors that I am concatenating `neighbors_mean` and `e`. What I don't understand is why the model trains as usual for several epochs and then suddenly the loss jumps to NaN.

Comment: You seem to be facing issue only utilising ReLU and performs well in sigmoid. Do try my suggestion provided in 3 choosing the right non saturation activation function,try different variant of ReLU like Leaky ReLU, randomized leaky ReLU (RReLU), parametric leaky ReLU (PReLU) or exponential linear unit (ELU)